# Access VBA click determines field

Tags: vba, ms-access

Here's what I'm trying to do using Access/VBA:
I have a field in a form that correlates to a phone number.  However, what I need to do is have the entry populate one of two fields in the table upon entry.  What I mean is that when a person enters a number in the text box, and does not check in the check box next to it, the text will populate the HOME phone field in the table.  But if the check box is checked, the text will populate the WORK phone field in the table.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AfterUpdate event of your checkbox place code like this:

```
Me.txtPhone.ControlSource = IIf(Me.chkSwitch, "Work", "Home")
```

Comment: Thank you.  However, it doesn't seem to like that chkSwitch is null if it's not clicked. Ideas?

Comment: Set default value 0 for this checkbox

Comment: If the answer worked for you, please mark it as accepted and upvote (useful), it will help others